# Read number from table on site without attributes or tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem. I want to create a script. It should read two numbers from other website but no id and class in div:

```
<td>
  1 IRR = <b>0.0698</b> Gold 
</td>
```

How can I read this numbers without any id or class in php?
or if it is hard in php how can I do it in js? or ajax?

Comment: In JS or PHP? Choose one

Comment: use tag name and nth-child paths in your css/xpath

Comment: php is better than js for me. but if it is hard in php i can do it in js

Comment: Then remove the JS tag

Comment: it's DOM. you don't **NEED** ids/classes to access things, just knowing where they are in the dom is enough. id/classes are just helpers.

Comment: do you want to read the number inside `<b>` tag?

Comment: yes i want to read inside <b>

Comment: it would be a LOT easier to do this in JS than PHP.

Comment: okay. can u write answer plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a server-side (PHP) solution, regular expressions are always a favourite.

```
// Your HTML variable
$html = "<td>
    1 IRR = <b>0.0698</b> Gold 
</td>";

preg_replace_callback("/<td>(?:[\s\r\n]+)?([0-9\.]+) irr = <b>([0-9\.]+)<\/b> gold(?:[\s\r\n]+)?<\/td>/im", function($m, $numa, $numb)
{
    // Your first number is in $numa
    // And your second is in $numb
}, $html);
```

For client side (js), you could use jQuery's filter function and a regular expression. It wouldn't be amazing in terms of performance but it would certainly do the trick.

```
var regexp = /^([0-9\.]+) irr = ([0-9\.]+) gold$/i;

$('td').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).text().trim().match(regexp);
}).each(function()
{
    var numbers = $(this).text().trim().replace(regexp, '$1,$2').split(',');

    // Now `numbers` is an array with the two numbers inside
});
```